# Perl: Print on the "display" and also into a file

Tags: string, perl, file, printing

Is there any way to print both onto the "display" and also into a file at the same time without repeating the print "string" code?

What I want to do:

```
if ($ofile) {
   open (FILE, '>>', "file");
   print "Hello" #some code#; #prints on the display and into the file
}
```

instead of:

```
if ($ofile) { open (FILE, '>>', "file"); }
print "Hello";
if ($ofile) { print FILE "Hello"; }
```

Tried googling but all I found was either or, not both features together.

Edit to add questions:

Then use IO::Tee to create a new tee'd handle, and then select $tee so that print uses it by default. – Eric Strom

@EricStrom What do you mean by create a new tee'd handle? Do you mean this `Local::TeeOutput`? search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.34/lib/Log/Log4perl.pm

@EricStrom Do you have an example?

@EricStrom Local::TeeOutput is not available in the default library for Strawberry Perl. Is there any alternative that's inside the default library?

Answer (score 10):

Sure, with [IO::Tee](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/IO::Tee) on CPAN.

```
my $tee = IO::Tee->new( \*STDOUT, \*STDERR, $John, $Tan );
print $tee "HELLO!\n";
```

To change perl's default handle:

```
select $tee;
print "HELLO!\n";
```

Comment: Hmm that's not what I'm looking for. I'm trying to keep it to the same exact line with the original print.

Comment: Then use `IO::Tee` to create a new tee'd handle, and then `select $tee` so that `print` uses it by default.

Comment: @EricStrom What do you mean by create a new tee'd handle? Do you mean this Local::TeeOutput]?  http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.34/lib/Log/Log4perl.pm

Comment: @EricStrom Do you have an example?

Comment: @EricStrom Local::TeeOutput is not available in the default library for Strawberry Perl. Is there any alternative that's inside the default library?

Comment: @JohnTan => Using the `IO::Tee` module, create a tee'd file handle that writes to STDOUT and your file.  Then use the `select` builtin to set that file handle as the target of an untargeted `print` or other io operator.

Comment: @JohnTan => the point of Strawberry Perl is that its `cpan` client works.  Just open a terminal window and type `cpan IO::Tee` or anything else you need.

Comment: IO::Tee does not appear to pass "make test" with Strawberry Perl on Windows.

Answer (score 7):

If this is for logging, Consider using [**Log::Log4perl**](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.34/lib/Log/Log4perl.pm)

You can have the same stuff log to the screen , file and even a database.

This is a complete example of logging to both the screen and a file.

```
use strict;
use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);
Log::Log4perl->easy_init("INFO");

my $logConfiguration = qq(
log4perl.logger        = INFO, Logfile, Screen
log4perl.appender.Logfile          =  Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
log4perl.appender.Logfile.filename = C:\\temp\\file.log
log4perl.appender.Logfile.layout   = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.Logfile.layout.ConversionPattern =%p[%d{MM/dd HH:mm} %3L] %m%n
log4perl.appender.Screen         = Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen
log4perl.appender.Screen.stderr  = 0
log4perl.appender.Screen.layout = Log::Log4perl::Layout::SimpleLayout
log4perl.appender.Screen.layout.ConversionPattern = %m%n
);

Log::Log4perl::init( \$logConfiguration );

INFO "This line will be logged";

ERROR "This error will be logged";

LOGDIE "Fatal error will be logged";
```

The configuration illustrates that both a file (**Logfile**) and the screen (**Screen**) will be appended when either `INFO` , `ERROR` etc are called.

The [FAQ](http://log4perl.sourceforge.net/releases/Log-Log4perl/docs/html/Log/Log4perl/FAQ.html) covers more questions

Comment: Does this api have to be installed or is it preinstalled with Strawberry Perl?

Comment: @parapura-rajikumar I just need to print something out. Do I use the print_portfolio subfunction from Log4perl?

Comment: @JohnTan Please see my edit to answer. I have a complete example. You will have to install Log4perl if your perl install doesn't already have it. Once you get the hang of it..  you will stop all prints :)

Answer (score 2):

See [Printing to multiple file handles with one request](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=214143) and [IO::MultiHandle - Operate on multiple file handles as one](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=214219) over at perlmonks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make subroutine for the task?

Also, many logging packages like [Log::Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Log%3a%3aLog4perl) support writing to both console and the file via quite simple configuration.

Comment: I just need to print something out. Do I use the print_portfolio subfunction from Log4perl?

Comment: @JohnTan - in that case, why not make subroutine `print_out` that will send its parameters to both streams? The Log4perl probably does not provide what you want then.