# Perl print output to same console and a file simultaneously

Tags: perl, stdout

I have 2 perl script file and I would like print the output (file 1 & file 2) to same console and a logfile simultaneously, how to do that? 
My script below will only print the file 2 output to console screen when it finish execute file 2. I need print the file 2 output to console realtime, not wait until it finish execute.

**File 1: test_perl.pl**

```
use File::Basename;
use strict;
use Env;

my $MSGOUT = \*STDOUT;
open( LOGFILE, ">/tmp/lofgile.txt" ) || die "Unable to open log file /tmp/lofgile.txt : $! \n\n";
$MSGOUT = \*LOGFILE;

my $output_log =`perl /tmp/test_perl_2.pl 2>&1`;
print $MSGOUT "$output_log";
```

**File 2: test_perl_2.p**l

```
use File::Basename;
use strict;
use Env;

print "Hello from test perl 2\n";

foreach my $i (0..100) {
  print "testing $i\n";
}
print "----------------\n";
sleep(5);
foreach my $i (101..200) {
  print "testing $i\n";
}
```

Comment: What about `$|` (see [perlvar](http://p3rl.org/perlvar))?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619505/perl-print-on-the-display-and-also-into-a-file

Comment: `open(FH, "| tee " . $outFilename) or die('Error');`